# How do you install and run Accumulo and Hadoop on OS X 10.7.4

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-zookeeper, accumulo

So I'm trying to run a MapReduce, word count example but I need to have Hadoop running.  I tried following instructions from **[here](http://harborsite.blogspot.com/2012/02/accumulo-on-mac-osx.html)** but it doesn't seem to be working.  The problem is the environment variable is not being set.  I added the line `setenv HADOOP_HOME /opt/hadoop-0.20.2` in `/etc/launchd.conf` but when I run `echo $HADOOP_HOME` it doesn't print the path.

Comment: If you don't absolutely have to have this in OSX to integrate with your development environment, I strongly suggest you try installing these in a VM running Linux.

Comment: @orangeoctopus I found better instructions from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brandonwerner/archive/2011/11/13/how-to-set-up-hadoop-on-os-x-lion-10-7.aspx).  Hadoop starts now but when I tried running an example it's having trouble connecting to the server. `12/06/18 13:42:03 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).`  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Set the **HADOOP_HOME** variable directly in Accumulo's ***conf/accumulo-env.sh*** script.